# Zabbix - Setup Web Scenario Trigger that accepts multiple response codes

Tags: monitoring, zabbix

I am running some Zabbix Web Scenario's to gather information on certain websites and API's for some of the API's 401 and 404 status codes are acceptable and I want to adopt these in the trigger expression. Currently they are considered to be "down" because they do not match the 200 response code.

I have created a Web Scenario in Zabbix that accepts the following response codes: 200, 401, 404 (currently hosting some API's so these are very common)

This Check was working fine when I was only allowing the 200 status code. To this check I have added 2 'OR' statements regarding the 401 and 404 status code. For some reason this confuses the trigger and every check "fails"

I had my trigger expression set up like this for the 200 status code check: (This works great!)

```
{Template App Nginx by Zabbix agent:web.test.error["Web Check Status 200, 401, 404"].last()}=0 or {Template App Nginx by Zabbix agent:web.test.fail["Web Check Status 200, 401, 404"].last()}>0 or {Template App Nginx by Zabbix agent:web.test.rspcode["Web Check Status 200, 401, 404","Web Check Status 200, 401, 404"].last()}<>200
```

For the 2 new status codes I changed it to this:

```
{Template App Nginx by Zabbix agent:web.test.error["Web Check Status 200, 401, 404"].last()}=0 or {Template App Nginx by Zabbix agent:web.test.fail["Web Check Status 200, 401, 404"].last()}>0 or {Template App Nginx by Zabbix agent:web.test.rspcode["Web Check Status 200, 401, 404","Web Check Status 200, 401, 404"].last()}<>200 or {Template App Nginx by Zabbix agent:web.test.rspcode["Web Check Status 200, 401, 404","Web Check Status 200, 401, 404"].last()}<>401 or {Template App Nginx by Zabbix agent:web.test.rspcode["Web Check Status 200, 401, 404","Web Check Status 200, 401, 404"].last()}<>404
```

Now how I understand the logic of the expression it is as follows:

Alert IF:

web.test.error is equal to 0 
OR web.test.fail is bigger then 0 
OR web.test.rspcode does not equal 200 
OR web.test.rspcode does not equal 401 
OR web.test.rspcode does not equal 404

Is my approach correct? And how can I fix this? 
Creating another trigger won't suffice (I think) because the original trigger will still be failing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Problem 1:**

Item `web.test.error` returns last error message of scenario as a string. So, your expression

```
{Template App Nginx by Zabbix agent:web.test.error["Web Check Status 200, 401, 404"].last()}=0
```

will never fire, as this item will never be *0*.
Change it to

```
{Template App Nginx by Zabbix agent:web.test.error["Web Check Status 200, 401, 404"].strlen()}>=0
```

and logical operator to *AND*.
This will solve the first problem.

**Problem 2:**

You dont need the `item.rspcode<>200 or item.rspcode<>401 or item.rspcode<>404` part. You already specified expected response codes in the web scenario.
What happens in your case:

- Zabbix receives HTTP 200: `item.rspcode<>401` and `item.rspcode<>404` are *TRUE*. Trigger is firing.
- Zabbix receives HTTP 401: `item.rspcode<>200` and `item.rspcdoe<>404` are *TRUE*. Trigger is firing.
- Zabbix receives HTTP 404: `item.rspcode<>200` and `item.rspcode<>401` are *TRUE*. Trigger is firing.

Remove aforementioned part from your trigger expression. It should solve problem 2.

**TL;DR**

Do it like this:

```
{Template App Nginx by Zabbix agent:web.test.error["Web Check Status 200, 401, 404"].strlen()}>=0 and
{Template App Nginx by Zabbix agent:web.test.fail["Web Check Status 200, 401, 404"].last()}>0
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed answer, this helped me solve the issue. I do have one remaining question. When I use the OR operator everything throws an alert but when I use AND only the things that are down throw an alert, why is that so?

Comment: When using OR, any of the statements needs to be True for an alert to fire. If you use my proposed solution with OR operator, the `web.test.error[].strlen()>=0` will cause trigger to fire, since it is always true - length of last error code is always bigger than 0.